# Laravel - ManyToMany Pivot Table With Other Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

In Laravel 5.2, lets say I have a `ManyToMany` relationship between two Models, `Post` and `Tag` (for the sake of example).  However, the pivot table between them also has a a relationship with another table:

```
posts:
  id
  name:

tags:
  id
  name:

posts_tags:
   post_id
   tag_id
   priority_id

priorities
   id:
   value:
```

As you can see, `posts_tags` represents the `many-to-many` relationship between `Post` and `Tag`.  However, that instance of that relationship, also has a `One To Many` relationship with `Priorities`

How do i handle setting up this sort of relationship in Eloquent?

Comment: priority hasMany Posts ?

Comment: @JilsonThomas it's not that simple unfortunately.  the priority applies to that specific instance of the relationship between the Post and the Tag.  Priority doesn't only apply to the Post

Comment: How would you call the priority in this case? Can you explain in simple English ?

Comment: @JilsonThomas essentially, there are several different priority levels and the posts are added to a queue of posts.  The relationship between the Post and the Tag represents a 'Queued' item.  However, each instance of this can have a Priority which is used by the client code to determine how each Post functions in the Queue.

Comment: The docs says: If your pivot table contains extra attributes, you must specify them when defining the relationship: `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->withPivot('column1', 'column2');`

Comment: @JilsonThomas i know, but this isn't an extra attribute, it's an extra relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the time being, I maintained my `ManyToMany` between `Post` and `Tag`, however, I am now simply storing the  `priority_id` as an attribute on the pivot table.  `Priority` only has an `ID` and a `Name`, so I've instead opted to store the mappings for `Priority` in Laravel config file.  So now, when I pull records for a particular `Post` and `Tag`, i can just pull `priority_id` as a column and map it to a value in my configuration, rather than store this data as an explicit relationship in the database:

```
<?php

return [

   'priorities' => [
       1 => 'first value',
       2 => 'second value',
       3 => 'third value',
       // etc
    ]
];
```